# Looking for the source of a scary story involving two brothers fighting off a type of ghoul trying to get to their sister

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I think it was in an anthology book of supposedly true scary stories, but it involved siblings inheriting a house next to an old church. Some kind of ghoul appeared outside the sisters' window a few different nights until the brothers waited for it and shot it. They contacted the local law man and they tracked this thing back to a crypt underneath the church where it was in a coffin with fresh bullet wounds. Does anyone know what book this is from?

Comment: Roughly when did you read this? What language was it in? Was it geared towards any particular age group (most anthologies like this seem to have been geared towards kids/young adults)? Do you have any memory of the cover of the book?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The story you're looking for is called the [Vampire of Croglin Grange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croglin_Grange).

> In the particularly dark tale written by Augustine Hare, several
>   episodes took place between 1875 and 1876. An old house had been
>   rented out to a woman and two brothers, Amelia, Edward and Michael
>   Cranswell. During one summer, Amelia was trying to sleep when a
>   strange creature appeared at her window and began picking out the lead
>   surrounding one of the window panes with a long fingernail, then
>   removing it and putting its hand through the resulting gap to undo the
>   window latch and let itself in. It was described as having a brown
>   face and flaming eyes. The vampire bit her in the throat. When her
>   brothers came into the room, the monster was gone. While one brother
>   tried to help his sister, the other went after the creature.
>
> After a trip to Switzerland, the three returned to Croglin Grange and
>   the creature returned again. The brother shot it in the leg and was
>   able to track it down to a vault in the local cemetery. They waited
>   until the next day to enter the vault, where they found the body of
>   the vampire resting inside a coffin and then burned it

Comment: With story-id answers, it's often useful if you can explain a little bit about how your suggestion matches the elements of the question.

Comment: Richard you nailed it! That is indeed the story, but I swore I read it in an anthology book with an X-rayed human skull on the cover. The think the only possible candidate is a newer publication of *Haunted Houses* by Charles G. Harper.